# Antd: Setting menu items with state property

Tags: reactjs, antd

The mapping method doesn't work for rendering sub menu items.

The state in this class.

```
class SideBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { fruits:["orange","peach","grape"] };

    }
```

The rendering part of this class.

```
<Menu>
<SubMenu 
   key="sub1" 
   title={<span><Icon type="mail" />
   <span>User-list</span></span>}>

   {this.state.fruits.map(function(item, i){
     <Menu.Item key={i}>{item}</Menu.Item>
   })}

</SubMenu>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's not clear to me exactly what you are expecting - can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from your function inside your map.
See this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/73w271now6?fontsize=14

```
{this.state.fruits.map(function(item, i) {
  return <Menu.Item key={i}>{item}</Menu.Item>;
})}
```

You can also create an arrow function there and omit the `return` keyword because you only have one line of code (you can read [this](https://codeburst.io/javascript-understand-arrow-function-syntax-ab4081bba85b) if you want more info about arrow functions), like this:

```
{
  this.state.fruits.map((item, i) => <Menu.Item key={i}>{item}</Menu.Item>)
}
```